# How to arrange items of folders of my project in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

How arrange my items in alphabetical order and by type? 
Folders first, Files after?

[image: my package explorer]

Comment: Try **Package Explorer** or **Navigator** view

Answer (score 0):

Err, it's a bit unclear what you're asking here. Eclipse does that by default :-) I mean the lexical ordering of folders, then the same for the files. Some special resources might be before them though.

OTOH, you could give a try to *Package explorer* instead of the *Project Explorer* (*Ctrl+3*, type *Package explorer*, *enter*). That does not enumerate additional resource folders.

Another thing you may try is to press that tiny white triangle in the upper right corner of the view, and select *Customize View*. There you have some additional options.

That's all in there by default for Eclipse. If you need something more sophisticated, you have to search for a specific plugin that fits your needs.